# Nice effects when scrolling down

Tags: jquery, html, css

When you go to [this site](http://www.oasiscreative.com/hosting/), you will see that the items have some nice effects when you scroll the page down. How can I do this?

I know how to handle with jQuery or CSS effects but how do I get those effects activated whenever you scroll down the page?

Comment: it's all css and some extra jquery plugins magic.

Comment: this is a ridiculous question. What exactly do you want to know? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That effect is achieved by CSS3 Transitions and transforms. I was actually looking this up myself a few weeks ago and just implemented it on my website. Here is an easy tutorial that will get you the desired results in no time: http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery

Basically how it works is that you have 2 scripts, animate.css & viewportchecker.js. Animate.css contains the styling for all those cool transitions like fade in, slide out etc. viewportchecker.js on the other hand contains a script that determines which DOM elements are currently in view.

The two are combined so as to dynamically add css classes to elements in view.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="viewportchecker.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(.animated-element).addClass("hidden").viewportchecker({
        classToAdd: "visible animated fadeIn", //class to add to elements when they are in view
        offset: 100 // duration of transition in milliseconds
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are usually [CSS3 transitions.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

They are being *applied* to the elements as the user *scrolls* on the page.

You can either:

- Write CSS3 transitions yourself
- Use a library that has pre-made transition classes, such as this [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: Thank you, Animate.css is really nice!